# How do I expire a session after one hour, like cookies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

How do I set up a session value that expires `1.hours` from now in Rails?

Cookies have an option like:

```
cookies[:thing] = {:value => {:normal => "session stuff"}, :expires => 2.hours.from_now}
```

Are there any options for sessions too?

Comment: Which gem do you use for session management? If none, you should write your own session expiration filters, like [there](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/7400) or use `Devise` ([docs](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)) that have `timeoutable` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please try this

```
session[:expires_at] = 60.minutes.from_now
```

you can also try

```
session[:expires_at] = Time.now + 60.minutes
session[:expires_at] = Time.now + 1.hour
session[:expires_at] = Time.now + 3600 #1 hour in seconds
```

All these are working in my application. Please do not forget to consider time zone.

Comment: Sorry this is not working.. Can we add some sweepers for this

Comment: session[:expires_at] will contain the time when the session has to expire...60.minutes.from_now is equal to Time.now + 60.minutes. It is working fine in my application.. what is the pbm you are facing?

Comment: There may be time zone issue, you can try session[:expires_at] = 60.minutes + Time.now in your required time zone.

Comment: Hi Raj,
request.session_options[:expire_after] = 1.hour
this worked for me. Thanks for the great help

Answer (score 4):

You can add this to your application controller:

```
before_filter :session_expires, :except => [:login, :logout]
before_filter :update_session_time, :except => [:login, :logout]

def session_expires
  @time_left = (session[:expires_at] - Time.now).to_i
  unless @time_left > 0
    reset_session
    flash[:error] = 'Lorem Ipsum.'
    redirect_to :controller => 'foo', :action => 'bar'
  end
end

def update_session_time
  session[:expires_at] = 60.minutes.from_now
end
```